# Is it possible to test for two new line characters in a row?

Tags: c, newline, c89

I'm trying to validate lines in a file with actual content in them, and exiting on cases where there are two empty lines in a row.  Can this be done?
This code results in fgetc() not catching the double carriage returns/new lines.

Code is a snippet from a C89 project, so declarations are made above snippet.

```
if ((file = fopen(fileName,"r")) == NULL)
{
    free(fileName);
    exit(1);
}

while (c != EOF)
{
    cOld = c;
    c = fgetc(file);

    /* count lines */
    if(c == '\n'){
        newLine++;
    }

    /* test for two carriage returns in a row */
    if(c == '\n' && cOld == '\n'){
        printf("ERROR: Invalid File\n");
        free(fileName);
        exit(1);
    }

}
```

Comment: Using a debugger will help you to resolve this kind of simple problems.

Comment: A handy tool for you to check whether your file contains '\r\n' or whatever, is [HexDump](http://www.fileformat.info/tool/hexdump.htm)

Comment: Notice that in hexadecimal ASCII, '\n' == 0A and '\r' == 0D

Comment: I use scite.  It has a built in visual end of line character.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that your are running your program on windows. In windows, end of line is represented by '\r\n'.

So when you check for c and cOld, they will not hold '\n' simultaneously.

> Text files created on DOS/Windows machines have different line endings
>   than files created on Unix/Linux. DOS uses carriage return and line
>   feed ("\r\n") as a line ending, which Unix uses just line feed ("\n").
>   You need to be careful about transferring files between Windows
>   machines and Unix machines to make sure the line endings are
>   translated properly.

Please follow this link for more details:
http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~krueger/csc209h/tut/line-endings.html

Comment: ...but the file I'm testing was written in windows... so yeah, I think that's the issue.  I'll do some testing based on that.  It was confusing because everything I've read says that all OSes can handle '\n' as a new line.

Comment: This solution worked.  I didn't need to follow any links, I just changed the file to have Unix line endings.  Things worked out well.  Thanks.

Comment: If the program is run on Windows (or DOS), and the file is opened in text mode, the stdio library will typically convert the two-byte line endings into a single `\n`. The problem occurs when Windows files are transfered to a non-Windows system without translation.